# iptables and TPROXY support

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables, tcp, ubuntu-14.04

I'm running iptables v1.4.21 on Ubuntu 14.04 and is trying to setup `iptables` to use `TPROXY`.

How can I check whether my current build of `iptables` supports `TPROXY`? I can check `TPROXY` support for HAProxy using `haproxy -vv`, is there something similar for `iptables`?

If there is no TPROXY support, does a TPROXY patch exist for iptables v1.4.21? Or is another version of iptables more suitable?

Answer (score 4):

Just try to use it and if iptables returns you some error related to "module not found", then check the situation? :-)

At least in my Ubuntu 14.04 installation there seems to be `xt_TPROXY.ko` in `/lib/modules/3.13.0-34-generic/kernel/net/netfilter/` directory so I presume Ubuntu has TPROXY support by default.

The `iptables` command itself does not contain support for anything, it merely uses the features compiled in to kernel (or kernel modules).